# What does locale-gen generate in Linux?

Tags: linux, locale

In my understanding, a locale is just a set of environment variables that indicate the system language and region.  But before we can use it, we need to edit `locale.gen` file to indicate what locale(s) you want to use and then run `locale-gen` command. So what does `locale-gen` do?  What data does `local-gen` generate? How can Linux use this data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In my understanding, a locale is just a set of evironment variables
>   that indicate the system language and region.

No, that is only part of the picture. A "locale" is, first of all, an **abstraction** for all the settings and information that is specific to a particular place (a country, a region etc.). In practice, on Linux, the locale infrastructure is provided by the C library (which, on Linux is usually the [GNU C Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library)). There are various things working together as part of this locale infrastructure:

- A set of functions that change behaviour based on the "current locale". These are provided by the C library, where the exact change depends on the function. For example, the `printf` family of functions will format output differently depending on locale (see [printf(3)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/printf.3.en.html) ).
- A database with information on how to behave in different locales. Instead of hardcoding behaviour in different locales in each locale-dependent function (see above), this information (the **locale information**) is extracted into a database. It contains things like which day is the start of the week, and what format to use for printing numbers.
- A way to set the "current locale". That's where the "set of environment variables" comes in - that is one way to set the current locale.

For further reading, I recommend the documentation of the GNU C Library: [7 Locales and Internationalization](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locales.html#Locales).

> But before we can use it, we need to edit locale.gen file to indicate
>   what locale(s) you want to use and then run locale-gen command. So
>   what does locale-gen do? What data does local-gen generate? How can
>   linux use these data?

`locale-gen` generates (or rather compiles) the "locale information" I mentioned above, by invoking `localedef`. The locale information is present in a textual format, which is easy to edit but hard to read for software (just like software source code). `locale-gen` and `localedef` compile this information into a binary format that is easier to read, and which is the data that the C library will use.

Since this binary format can take a lot of disk space, it is only generated for the locales that are actually used. That is what you can configure in locale.gen.

Also read the manpages of `locale-gen` and `localedef`, they explain this quite well: [locale-gen(8)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/locales/locale-gen.8.en.html), [localedef(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages/localedef.1.en.html).

Comment: Thank, helps a lot.